# What time of ProtoBuf to use in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, protocol-buffers

I am trying to create protobuf in c# and I see some videos using protoContract and protoMember like

```
[protoContract]
public class tutorial
{
     [ProtoMember(1)]
     public string name {get;set;}
     [ProtoMember(2)]
     public string email {get;set;}
}
```

and then it serializes and deserializes while some code uses

```
message ABC
{
String name = 1;
String email = 2;
}
```

Which one to use when ?

Comment: The first is C# code, the second is a proto file that just defines how the protobuf message looks and can be used to generate that C# code (or code in one of many other languages)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Got it. How can I read from proto files then ? Can you provide some example or example links ? Do I need to use grpc only for proto files ?